# Flutter Horizontal gridview with dynamic width

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have tried using [Flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view), but it seems as though that its built better for vertical scrolling.

My goal is to have a horizontal gridview with dynamic widths to make the grid feel natural and not so spread apart

This is what I have (I removed some of the UI code, but its essentially the same)

```dart
GridView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: sourceList.length,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: .3),
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    final e = sourceList[i];
    return Text(
      e.name,
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

And this is what I am looking for

[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure, which is why I'm commenting but can you just have the child aspect ratio as a variable and then modify it based on mediaQuery.of(context).size.width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the max I could achieve by using **ternary operator** to adjust `mainAxisCellCount`. You can adjust the the count according to the length of you shortest and longest string.

```
   Container(
            height: 180.0,
            child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: 8,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>  Container(
                child: Center(child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                    child: Chip(
                        label: Text('${fruits[index]}', overflow: TextOverflow.visible, maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(),)))),
              ),
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.count(2, fruits[index].length > 3 ? fruits[index].length > 8 ? fruits[index].length > 2 ? 4 : 3 : 2 : 1),
              mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
            ),
          ),
```

[image]